# How to Count Records between Two Records in T-SQL Without Cursor? And what is this type of data layout called?

Tags: t-sql

I am presented with some interesting data at work.  It's in a layout similar to this:

```
 DATE
 Tran ID TRANSACTION
 Tran ID TRANSACTION
 Tran ID TRANSACTION
 NEXT DATE
 Tran ID TRANSACTION
 Tran ID TRANSACTION
 THIRD DATE
 Tran ID TRANSACTION
```

For Example:

```
 20140219
 Tran 1 10.00
 Tran 1 Beneficiary ABC Originator XYZ
 Tran 2 20.00
 Tran 2 Beneficiary 123 Originator ABC
 Tran 2 NOTE: bleh bleh bleh
 Tran 3 10.00
 Tran 3 Beneficiary XYZ originator ABC
 20140218
 Tran 4 10.00
 Tran 4 Beneficiary ABC Originator XYZ
 Tran 5 20.00
 Tran 5 Beneficiary 123 Originator ABC
```

First of all, what is this layout called?  It looks like there's one record of date and the addenda to the date are the transactions, but each transaction is dependent on the Tran ID.  Transactions with the same ID are related.

Second, I am trying to count the records for each date.  So for the example provided it would be

```
 20140219 = 8 Records
 20140218 = 5 Records
```

So far, I am only able to achieve this by creating an extra column and using a cursor to loop through the string and look fro date within the first 8 characters.  If 1st 8 characters is a date then update, then assign the date to a variable and assign the variable to all the following strings until it hits the next date and update the date again.  So the data looks something like this:

```
 Manipulated Data:
 20140219 20140219 
 20140219 Tran 1 10.00
 20140219 Tran 1 Beneficiary ABC Originator XYZ
 20140219 Tran 2 20.00
 20140219 Tran 2 Beneficiary 123 Originator ABC
 20140219 Tran 2 NOTE: bleh bleh bleh
 20140219 Tran 3 10.00
 20140219 Tran 3 Beneficiary XYZ originator ABC
 20140218 20140218 
 20140218 Tran 4 10.00
 20140218 Tran 4 Beneficiary ABC Originator XYZ
 20140218 Tran 5 20.00
 20140218 Tran 5 Beneficiary 123 Originator ABC
```

Then I use the following query to count up the information:

```
 SELECT LEFT(string,8), COUNT(*) FROM table
 GROUP BY Left(string,8)
```

However, I was told "a good query writer can write codes without cursor".  Currently I am mind blown on how to do this without cursor.  I've seem some pretty creative ways to overcome issues on StackOverflow and I figure I'll ask it here to see if anyone has a solution to this.

Comment: "what is this layout called?" A mess that has no business in a relational database.

Comment: Often, report writers are trying to make this format from a table, but this looks to be the reverse of such a process (make a table from a report). Where does this data come from? Is this one big string in a variable? How are you currently getting this into a table to query?

Comment: What database?  There is no inherit order to a table.  If you added a date column then why did not not add it as a date?

Comment: The data comes in as a flat text file from a vendor.  It's all I have since I don't have access to the database at the vendor.

Answer (score 0):

If you get that as a flat file that you load then at a minimum put an iden PK on the table so you can reproduce the order.

No you cannot parse that data without a cursor.
But why wait to load it to parse it?
Read it line by line in .NET or a framework of your preference and parse it out then.

I see
iden(PK)  int32
date DateTime
tran SmallInt
text varchar(800)

You could break it down further to amount, beneficiary, originator, and note
The parse would be bit more complex but not bad